# Components PWM vs. Variable Voltage

Tags: gpio

It is my understanding that there are two commonly used ways that components send analog data to microprocessors, PWM and variable voltage.

Is it correct that Raspberry Pi can do PWM with undersampling, but can't do variable voltage at all?

I'm dealing with a infrared distance measurement sensor from Sharp.

Answer (score 3):

The Pi only has digital I/O (all the GPIO are 3V3 digital only).

So you need an external ADC if you wish to read an analogue voltage.

If you read a GPIO frequently enough (or react to level change interrupts) you can interpret PWM inputs.  In practical terms you are probably talking about PWM frequencies of less than 100kHz.